# Is there a catch-all term for the sector of “non-business” employers: NGOs, non profits, professional societies, government, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

*Note: I asked the same question in the Workplace forum but it was closed and I was asked to re-ask here.*

I am looking for a concise and professional-sounding expression to use in my resumes and bios to explain that my career history covered "non-business" employment as well, in addition to businesses. This is to emphasize my diverse experience, but without going into too many details (as my ultimate focus will be business-related).

When I say "non-business" I mean: NGOs, NPOs, government, professional societies, institutions.

I already discarded "non-profit" as that hints at "volunteering" — which is not the only thing I did. I have done a lot of contract work with local government branches and authority as well as professional societies. "Public sector" would exclude private not-for-profits.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Non-private, perhaps? Not exactly elegant, though…

Comment: The public and charitable sector?

Comment: Provided professional contract services for non-profits, private, and public sectors.  However, I wouldn't necessarily discount the details regardless of being paid or not.  Who cares really?  If you led a team of 6 people to achieve a publicity campaign that raised $300k, or designed a website on budget and on time for a non-profit, that's important info.

Comment: Private not-for-profits are still generally referred to as public sector.

Answer (score 2):

The term "noncommercial" exists:

> [noncommercial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noncommercial) — 1. (Commerce) not of, connected with, or involved in commerce: noncommercial organizations.

This seems very similar in definition to nonprofit organizations. Wikipedia seems to consider them roughly the same:

> A nonprofit organization, or not-for-profit organization, often called a nonprofit and non-commercial organization is an organization that uses surplus revenues to achieve its goals rather than distributing them as profit or dividends.

The pair of terms seems relatively common so I suggest "various nonprofit and noncommercial organizations."